# An element access expression should take an argument

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular I have tried to create some sample application but getting error. Please help. I am trying to make my own from googles project (https://stackblitz.com/angular/ooqemvjyqkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts)
When I remove array from `users = User[];` it works fine but it does not give a build. (`[ts] Type 'User[]' is not assignable to type 'typeof User'`). With `users = User[];` it does not even compile. (suggestion [ts] An element access expression should take an argument.(any)) .

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from '../user';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedUser: User;

  users = User[]; // review use of array type. users = User[];

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  onSelect(user: User): void {
    this.selectedUser = user;
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
  }

    save(): void {
    this.userService.updateUser(this.users);
  }

  add(name: string): void {
    console.log(name);
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.userService.addUser({ name } as User)
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.users.push(user);
      });
  }
}
```

////////////////////user.ts///////////////

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }
```

///////////////user.service.ts////////////////

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from './user';
// import { USERS } from '../assets/data/userData';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class UserService {

  private usersUrl = 'api/users';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    // return of(USERS);
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.usersUrl);
  }

  /** GET user by id. Will 404 if id not found */
getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
  const url = `${this.usersUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<User>(url);
}

/** PUT: update the user on the server */
updateUser (user: User): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.put(this.usersUrl, user, httpOptions);
}

/** POST: add a new user to the server */
addUser (user: User): Observable<User> {
  return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, user, httpOptions);
}

/* GET users whose name contains search term */
searchUsers(term: string): Observable<User[]> {
  if (!term.trim()) {
    // if not search term, return empty hero array.
    return of([]);
  }
  return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.usersUrl}/?name=${term}`);
}

}
```

Comment: It depends what you trying to achieve but this line ``users = User[];`` is wrong. If you want to just specify type it should be ``users: User[];`` but if u want to assign empty array then ``users: User[] = [];``

Comment: Thank you. But when I use users: User[] it gives me error in save method. ([ts]
Argument of type 'User[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'User[]'.)

Comment: You should include the code for `userService.updateUser`. The problem now is this expects a single `User` but you're trying pass a `User[]`.

Comment: As Kirk Larkin noted, you are passing `this.users` (which is an array of `User`s) to `this.userService.updateUser` (which takes only a single `User`).  What were you trying to do?  Did you mean to update only the selected user or to update each user individually (in which case you would have to loop over `this.users`)?

Comment: I have added please review and help me.

Answer (score 38):

Replace

```
users = User[];
```

with

```
user: User[]
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: users: User[] it gives me error in save method. ([ts] Argument of type 'User[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'. Property 'id' is missing in type 'User[]'.)

Comment: It would be much better if you explained WHY this will "do the trick" or at least reference external documentation.

Answer (score 15):

The correct syntax for me was **not**

```
user: User[] = User[] // WRONG SYNTAX
```

but

```
users: User[] = []
```

or

```
users: User[] = new Array<User>()
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
    users = [Users];
```

I find that syntax tends to work better.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this trying to compile a standalone typescript file with tsc. In my case I had to change this:

```
users: User[];
```

to this:

```
let users: User[];
```

Answer (score 0):

As some people wrote before, you try to add `User[]` which is an array to a method that only needs one single user. You access one element of an arry, by writing the following code:

```
save(): void {
    this.userService.updateUser(this.users[THE_INDEX_FROM_THE_CURRENT_USER]);
}
```

That should only give one `User` to the `updateUser()`

So in general:

```
oneArray: Foo[];         <-   creates an array named 'oneArray' with Foo objects inside
oneFoo = oneArray[0];    <-   Gives you the first element of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

do not adding users = User[], as you are getting users from service. instead just declare the type like
users: User[];

Above will work